# If an app is created with libs from different author with MIT license, which one will be applicable?

Tags: mit

If an app is created with different library (all MIT) from different authors, than please advise following:

1. Do this app need to include all those licenses in the final binary release ?
2. As the MIT license of these authors will be added, do this means the user of this app can resell this app again branding it as their own ?, considering below lines from MIT:

```
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software..... sell copies of the Software ....

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to reproduce the license text and copyright notices in your application. This does not have to be obnoxious but should (at least as good manners) be findable. Go to `about:credits` or `chrome://credits` in your web browser right now to see a long, long list of such notices.
2. The MIT licenses does not need to apply to *your* software. This means you should notify recipients that you make use of others' MIT-licensed software (and who those other authors are, via their copyright notices), but you can license your application under any terms, as long as you preserve the MIT notices.

   It would, in fact, be most clear you said outright what specific MIT libraries you used, and what the notices are for each of them. This gives the clearest possible credit to the library authors and, at the same time, lets you make it clear that the MIT licenses apply to each library only, not to your application.